# Generics variable declaration with extends possible?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a generic typescript class:

```
class MyClass<T extends BaseClass> {}
```

When declaring a variable I want to keep the type generic so that any object of type MyClass can be assigned to it. My aim would be:

```
let myVariable : MyClass<T extends BaseClass>;
```

Unfortunately I cannot find a way to do this. What would work is this:

```
let myVariable : MyClass<any>;
```

But this is not optimal because then I loose the information that T is extending from BaseClass. I would appreciate any hints how this can be done.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TS Playground](//www.typescriptlang.org/play), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing. This allows those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case. ‣ The code here is *too* minimal; `MyClass` is empty, so `MyClass<A>` and `MyClass<B>` are identical. Whether this is possible depends on how `MyClass` depends on `T`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to build a reproduction in [www.typescriptlang.org](http://www.typescriptlang.org) I realized that in pure typescript everything works as expected:

```
let myVariable : MyClass<BaseClass>;
```

Then I can do:

```
class A extends BaseClass {};
myVariable = new MyClass<A>();
```

The problem seems to be with Angular templates where I originally got the compile errors. I mistakenly confused this with a typescript problem.